# How to make CLOB column in group by expression? Any work around?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, ora-00932

I have a below query:

```
    SELECT
    Test_Case_Name,
    Test_Case_Description,
    Test_Case_Status,
CASE WHEN Test_Case_Status = 'FAILED' THEN
    LISTAGG(LN.LN_BUG_ID,', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY LN.LN_BUG_ID)
END AS Defect_ID
FROM Test LEFT JOIN LINK LN ON
    LN.LN_ENTITY_ID=Test.TS_TEST_ID
GROUP BY
    Test_Case_Name,
    Test_Case_Description,
    Test_Case_Status
```

When I run this query, I get the error

> ORA-00932: inconsistent data types Expected got CLOB

This is because the column `Test_Case_Description` is a `CLOB` data type. If I comment this column from select clause it works fine but I need this column in the output.

The above query is a simplified version of the original query [here](http://pastebin.com/PLVZNJZv)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the syntax you might want to use for your requirement:

Syntax:

```
DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR (lob_loc, amount, offset)

Parameter Description 
lob_loc: Locator for the LOB to be read i.e CLOB column name. 
amount: Number of bytes (for BLOBs) or characters (for CLOBs) to be read. 
offset: Offset in bytes (for BLOBs) or characters (for CLOBs) from the start of the LOB (origin: 1).
```

So your final query should be something like this,

```
    SELECT
    Test_Case_Name,
    DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(Test_Case_Description,2000,1) as Test_Case_Description,
    Test_Case_Status,
CASE WHEN Test_Case_Status = 'FAILED' THEN
    LISTAGG(LN.LN_BUG_ID,', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY LN.LN_BUG_ID)
END AS Defect_ID
FROM Test LEFT JOIN LINK LN ON
    LN.LN_ENTITY_ID=Test.TS_TEST_ID
GROUP BY
    Test_Case_Name,
    Test_Case_Description,
    Test_Case_Status
```

Since you are concerned about not loosing data after 4000 characters,
my suggestion is to divide the column and display it as below..

```
SELECT
    Test_Case_Name,
    DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(Test_Case_Description,4000,1) as Test_Case_Description1,
    DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(Test_Case_Description,8000,4001) as Test_Case_Description2
    Test_Case_Status,
CASE WHEN Test_Case_Status = 'FAILED' THEN
    LISTAGG(LN.LN_BUG_ID,', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY LN.LN_BUG_ID)
END AS Defect_ID
FROM Test LEFT JOIN LINK LN ON
    LN.LN_ENTITY_ID=Test.TS_TEST_ID
GROUP BY
    Test_Case_Name,
    Test_Case_Description1,
    Test_Case_Description2,
    Test_Case_Status
```

Comment: yeah in such case you can print that column in a plsql block. PL SQL block has limition of more than 4000 characters..

Comment: Could you please let me know how to do that? Any link? Thanks so much

Comment: I give you one more idea. can you tell me the max length of that column

Comment: Currently, It is 4292..but in future it may increase

Comment: Did you see my edited answer. Splitting and selecting. that will be a best option.. You don need to worry about your column size increase

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21690/discussion-between-javanoob-and-mari)

Answer (score 2):

I just changed my query to as mentioned below and it worked:

```
SELECT 
    InnerTable.Test_Case_Name,
    Test.Test_Case_Description,
    InnerTable.Test_Case_Status,
FROM 
    (   SELECT
    Test_Case_ID
    Test_Case_Name,
    Test_Case_Status,
CASE WHEN Test_Case_Status = 'FAILED' THEN
    LISTAGG(LN.LN_BUG_ID,', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY LN.LN_BUG_ID)
END AS Defect_ID
FROM Test LEFT JOIN LINK LN ON
    LN.LN_ENTITY_ID=Test.TS_TEST_ID
GROUP BY
    Test_Case_Name,
    Test_Case_Status ) AS InnerTable INNERJOIN TEST ON InnerTable.Test_Case_ID = Test.Test_Case_ID
```