# How to fix 'ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB' when used with GROUP BY clause?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm creating a view for a business logic, which has around 25 columns from multiple tables. One of the fields, say 'person_description', has around 10000 characters, which I do not want to truncate.

I'll provide a small sample (the actual query is much bigger) for the sake of simplicity.

```
create view sample_description as 
select person_description, name, employee_id
from employee_table 
group by person_description, name, employee_id;
```

I am getting an error of 'ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB', on the `person_description` field.

My understanding about this problem is that, GROUP BY clause does not work on clob field. I do not want to use SUBSTR and truncate the field as it is important to get the entire content as is.

I'm looking for any kind of workaround or solution on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That query is invalid. You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: What are you trying to do? GROUP BY a clob column seems a bit strange.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make CLOB column in group by expression? Any work around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033147/how-to-make-clob-column-in-group-by-expression-any-work-around)

Comment: Why would you group by person_description in the first place?

Comment: It seems like you have oversimplified your posted code. You need to post something which demonstrates the business rules you are trying to implement as well as reproducing the problem you have. If your code doesn't make sense to us we cannot explain how to solve it.

Comment: @jarlh Oops, was a mistake. I've edited the sample query.

Comment: @eckes, I don't need to group by person_description column at all. I have other columns where I'll be using aggregation queries, for which I'll have to use group by. So, I'm kinda forced to add the person_description field.

Comment: You need to post some sample data and required output from that data.

Comment: Don’t add it to the group by if you don’t aggregate by it. Anyway, in all cases you can’t aggregate by a clob field, if you need it for a result it is probably easiest to join or look the values up (yet again I can’t think of a case for an aggregated description field (or for multiple matches)

Answer (score 0):

Try with to_char:

```
create view sample_description as 
select person_description, name, employee_id
from employee_table 
group by TO_CHAR(person_description), name, review_id;
```

It only works when clob < 4000 characters

Comment: This won't work if the CLOB is > 4000 characters (limit of varchar2) and the OP clearly states in their question *" `person_description` has around 10000 characters, which I do not want to truncate"*

Comment: It only works when clob < 4000 characters - CLEARLY noted -.-

Comment: Yes, your post has it *"CLEARLY noted"*. But it still is not an answer that **solves the OP's actual problem**, which is handling CLOBS > 4000 characters.

Answer (score 0):

to stick with your 'example' you could add the clob column after grouping. I am assuming employee_id is your primary key. HTH KR Peter

```
create view sample_description as 
select
    (select e2.person_description from employee_table e2 where e2.employee_id = e.employee_id)
    , e.name, e.employee_id
from
    (select ei.name, ei.employee_id
    from employee_table ei
    group by ei.name, ei.employee_id) e;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW sample_description AS 
SELECT person_description, name, employee_id
  FROM employee_table 
 WHERE employee_id IN (SELECT employee_id OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id, NAME) 
                         FROM employee_table);
```